# C++ Struct Puzzle Unable to be Compiled

Tags: c++, struct, dev-c++

I have this code snippet from a C++ book:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct S1
{
    const char *s;
    int i;
    struct S1 *slp;
};

main()
{
    static struct S1 a[]= {{"abcdef", 1, a+1},
                    {"ghijkl", 2, a+2},
                    {"mnopqr", 3, a} };

    struct S1 *p = a;

    printf("a[0].s = %s   p-> = %s   a[2].slp->s = %s \n", a[0].s, p->s, a[2].slp->s);

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("--a[i].i    = %d   ", --a[i].i);
        printf("++a[i].s[3] = %c \n", ++a[i].s[3]);
    }
}
```

Using Dev C++ v5.11, I am unable to compile it with an error code:

```
[Error] increment of read-only location '*(a[i].S1::s + 3u)'
```

Solution as commented by @Corristo works.

Thanks for the help everyone. I'll get better IDE and books for the next time. Thanks, @Tomaz-Canabrava.

Comment: I think this C++ book is not C++ at all...

Comment: This looks more like C from the early 90s than proper C++. You should get a better C++ book.

Comment: `s` is `const char*`, then `s[3]` is `const char`, you can't perform `++` on it.

Comment: Is this really a C++ book? Does it have the two + symbols on the cover? If so, I suggest you bury this book (don't burn it, no need to contribute to global warming) and get yourself a better one.

Comment: can you give any reference to the book  name, author, pagenumber  etc ?

Comment: anyways in this case the strings `abcdef` , `ghijkl` and `mnopqr` are stored at read only locations you cant just change them this way ....

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Any way to make this code run?

Comment: No way and no need. It won't teach you anything useful anyway. Just ignore this book.

Comment: @Yosua You can replacce `++a[i].s[3]` by `a[i].s[3] + 1`. However, this will not modify the `const char*` C-string. If that is what you need, use a `std::string` in the struct instead of `const char*`.

Comment: @Corristo Thanks. That compiles without problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Stop using Dev C++***

- this is a substandard IDE made in the early's 2000 and **never** should be used by **anyone**, nor universities, nor students. simply put: It has more bugs than anything else. (unfortunately, it's the IDE of choice of almost all brazilian universities, sigh.)

**Get a Proper C++ book**

- If it says that it will teach you **anything** below C++11, it's not a proper C++ book and it will teach you usually **wrong** c++ from the medieval age (pre C++11)

**Do Not go with anything related to Turbo C++**

- Seriously, there's universities still using that to teach C++.

There are a **LOT** of good and free books, compilers and IDE's around, since you are in windows I would recomend one of those Free IDEs:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Express
- Qt Creator
- Eclipse CDT

This at least will give you a modern C++, not from the stone age.
Good Study.

Comment: Code::Blocks is decent enough for beginners, and CLion is free for students, too.

Comment: CLion is very good - I didn't added on the list because I didn't know it was free for students. Code::Blocks I would'nt recommend because development seems to have stagnated like DevC++

Answer (score 0):

**1.** C++ does not support default `int` in `main()`, should add `int` as return value:

```
int main()
{
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

**2.** Structure `S1.s` is `const char *`, means its value cannot be changed, so you can't do `++a[i].s[3]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Removing const will compile the code, but crash the program.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, examples like that have a specific purpose, such as, this code is valid for a particular version of a language definition.

This one might be demonstrating that const is not really const. The author may be assuming ANSI C++.

It also might be demonsrating a bug in a particular complier.

I would look at your complier settings and see if you can change the language to an earilier standard.